# Unicode in clean Rails app URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode

This is my code in my model:

```
def to_param
  require 'unicode'
  "#{id}-#{Unicode::normalize_KD("-"+name+"-").downcase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,'-')}".gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')
end
```

I needed the `unicode` feature because in the name of my certain entries, it consists of accent (foreign characters). Without the `unicode` it was set to replace the accent character with a `-`.

But the problem right now is it gives me the following error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (no such file to load -- unicode) on line #50 of app/views/spots/index.html.erb:
47: 
48:               <% @shops.each do |spot| %>
49:                 <div id="<%= dom_id(shop) %>" class="item">
50:                   <a href="<%= shop_path(shop, :type => @type) %>">
51:                     <% if !shop.photos.blank? %>
52:                       <%= image_tag(shop.photos.last.url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail') %>
53:                     <% else %>
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `unicode` gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'unicode'
```

Comment: I usually change my code live in production due to the problem with local machine configuration problem. I usually apply an Apache restart after code change. After adding the gem, do I restart Apache like I used to to take effect? Thanks.

Comment: Since I am running the Rails app on Passenger, I did the following to install the gem: `sudo /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem install unicode` Thanks.